# How to match unicode words with ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I'm using ruby 1.9 and trying to find out which regex I need to make this true:

```
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
"föö".match(/(\w+)/u)[1] == "föö"
# => false
```

Comment: You have to convert both the string to the same unicode than you can match it. With Iconv you can convert your string to specific unicode.

Comment: Added default Encoding. Still doesn't work...

Comment: Try place comment "# coding utf-8" at the beginning of script and make sure, that script file is utf-8.

Comment: Use `[/(\w+)/u,1]` - it's shorter. Or even just `[/\w+/u]`, because `()` in your regexp takes all.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
# encoding=utf-8 
p "föö".match(/\p{Word}+/)[0] == "föö"
```

Comment: Crazy that you need to tag the source code as UTF8 to make the regexp behave correctly with the correct encoding. Thx a lot !

Comment: A good documentation for that can be found here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Character+Properties

Answer (score 1):

You can [manually turn on Unicode matching](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/11-regular-extremism.html#turn-on-unicode-matching-for-w-d-s-and-b) using the inside `(?u)` syntax:

```
"föö".match(/(?u)(\w+)/)[1] == "föö"
# => true
```

However, using Unicode Property Syntax (steenslag's answer) or POSIX Brackets Syntax is better style, since they both automatically respect Unicode codepoints:

```
"föö".match(/(\p{word}+)/)[1] == "föö"
# => true

"föö".match(/([[:word:]]+)/)[1] == "föö"
# => true
```

See [this blog post](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/30-regex-with-class.html) for more info about matching Unicode characters in Ruby regexes.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/208777

and

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/210770

might have clues for you.

You can also use the (documented) `\p{L}` property, ex:

```
$ ruby -ve "p '℉üüü' =~ /\p{L}/"
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
1
```